# When pressing enter on popup the submit buttons on landing page gets triggered

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a page with two submit buttons which also opens up a popup (id : addPopup) having another submit button. Whenever Enter is pressed on the popup the first submit button on the landing page is triggered, however I want to invoke the button on the popup instead. 
This is the code for the Submit button on popup:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="continueButton" styleClass="btn btn-primary"  
                    value="Continue" 
                    action="#{optionsController.continue()}"
                    render="menuPanel addSection addOptionsPanel"
                    oncomplete="if(#{empty facesContext.messageList})#{rich:component('addPopup')}.hide();"
                    disabled="#{empty optionsController.addParcelId and  empty optionsController.addGridReference}"  />
```

I have tried using richfaces hotkey, but it doesn't work and the page gets submitted

```
<rich:hotKey selector="#addPopup" enabledInInput="true" key="return" preventDefault="true"/>
```

Also have tried using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Return', function(e){
        key  = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 13){
            var continueBtn = document.getElementById('continueButton'));               
            continueBtn.click();
    }
```

});

but this does not work either.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or any other approach that might work?

Comment: Are you using `prependId="false" on the form? If not then your selectors are not going to find anything.

Comment: It seems that the <h:body> generates an id of its own and appends it to the child elements due to which            document.getElementById('continueButton')); fails to find the element. Tried adding an explicit id but it is ignored. Is there any way we can force this id not to be added to the child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to handle the enter key by using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Return', function(e){
        key  = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 13){  // Enter key pressed
            // Get button binding from backing bean.        
            var continueBtn = document.getElementById("#{optionsController.continueButton.clientId}");                 
            if(!continueBtn.disabled){
                continueBtn.click();
            }
            return false;
        }  
});
```

Also added the binding for the continueButton in the backing bean, along with getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

Try to have the popup-content rendered in an own `<h:form>`, this way the Enter will trigger the form you are currently in.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="loginPopup" show="true">
    <h:form id="login" class="compact-form clearfix">

    </h:form> 
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Within the `rich:popupPanel`, you can decide via the attribute `domElementAttachment` where the popup has to be attached.

Hope it helps...